# Invalid parameter number in eloquent

Tags: php, pdo, eloquent

I've got this query :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;

$arr = [/* Array values here */];
$in = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$str = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... AND ... IN ($in)";
$select_categories = DB::select($str, $arr);
```

Now I'm getting the error `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number`, this is the stack trace :

> /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php:330 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(330): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(657): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database{closure}('SELECT categori...', Array) #2 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(624): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('SELECT categori...', Array, Object(Closure)) #3 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(333): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('SELECT name...', Array, Object(Closure)) #4 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Capsule/Manager.php(199): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('SELECT name...', Array) #5 /var/www/categ.class.php(81): Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager::__callStatic('select', Array) #6 /var/www/categ.class.php(123): Site\Naviga in /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php on line 664

I don't get why this is happening. I'm trying to echo the variables `$str` and `$arr` to try and see if the number of `?` matches the count of the array and indeed it does. So I can't see why is that error being generated. Any idea?

In the stack there are 3 arguments `run('SELECT name...', Array, Object(Closure))`, maybe this is causing the issue as it thinks there is a third parametre which there isn't? Or something like that?

EDIT :

`$str` contains : `"?,?,?,?,?,?"`

`$arr` contains : `[94, 91, 97, 92, 96, 90]`

Result of `dd($str, $arr);` :

```
"SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ORDER BY pro.sort_order"

array:14 [
  0 => "56"
  1 => "163"
  4 => "64"
  6 => "53"
  7 => "52"
  10 => "55"
  12 => "59"
  13 => "57"
  28 => "157"
  43 => "60"
  49 => "133"
  68 => "287"
  101 => "54"
  109 => "278"
]
```

Comment: Check what `$str` and `$arr` contains.

Comment: @SougataBose a string and an array. A string containing multiple `?`. And an array value for each `?`.

Comment: We can see that. Add what it actually contains.

Comment: You can use `whereIn('column', $arr)` instead of building your own query

Comment: @SougataBose added

Comment: @aynber thanks, I know, but I'm trying to understand where is the problem coming from, not looking for an alternative solution :-)

Comment: You're not using any other variables in the query, are you?

Comment: @aynber I am, but a "static" variable, not using any `?`, just an int variable that is attached to the string itself. It shouldn't affect anything logically. Also I can't use `whereIn` with `DB::select`

Comment: `DB::select(DB::raw(...))` or `DB::selectRaw(...)` for executing raw queries.

Comment: @iArcadia thanks for the comment but `DB::select()` works fine as it is, just in this case it doesn't and I'm wondering why.

Comment: Yes, I misread you question. About the `run()` you see in the stack, the third argument is a closure by default, that's why you see that.

Comment: @iArcadia oh okay so that's not the issue then ^^ Any idea then why am I getting the error even tho the parametres are correct? Or a way to debug this?

Comment: Please add the result of `dd($str, $arr);`.

Comment: You have no other `?` in your query? Without these of `$in`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir done

Comment: Try with `array_values($arr)` instead of only `$arr` (in your `select()`).

Comment: @iArcadia that worked, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use [`array_values($arr)`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-values.php) instead of `$arr` in the `select()` method:

```php
$select_categories = DB::select($str, array_values($arr));
```

`$in` has 14 `?` and `$arr` has 14 elements. The reason why it does not work is because indexes of `$arr` are not from `0` to `13` but from `0` to `109`. Since indexes are integer and not string, all of them from `0` to `109` exist even if some are `null`, so the size of `$arr` is `110`.

The effect of using `array_values()` on `$arr`:

```php
array:14 [
  0 => "56"
  1 => "163"
  2 => "64"
  3 => "53"
  4 => "52"
  5 => "55"
  6 => "59"
  7 => "57"
  8 => "157"
  9 => "60"
  10 => "133"
  11 => "287"
  12 => "54"
  13 => "278"
]
```